# Changing field values in form.clean_xxx

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to validate form input and if required modify a field used to build a subdomain for a URL. IE take out the illegal characters. Here is a VERY simple example to illustrate the problem.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def clean_f(self):
        f = self.cleaned_data['f']
        if f.count('%'):
            f = f.replace('%', '')
        return f
```

This doesn't change the form. I want the user to see the 'stripped' value, but it always shows the submitted value.

Is it possible to do this with a simple form clean_xxx method?
Otherwise I will use my AJAX form processor.

Thanks

Comment: Once the server does the clean, it would proceed to the models, and then the response would get rendered through the view, which the end user sees. So, you cannot do what you are looking for through the `clean` method. You are better off using jquery for that purpose

Comment: Thanks, will do it with Dajax :)